# What is the difference between a RibbonWindow and Window?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

Since i can also host a **Ribbon** in a normal **Window**, i want to know , which additional options the **RibbonWindow** offer? According to the source code I couldn't find any difference except the '**OnApplyTemplate**' method. When should I use this class instead of Window, when building a Ribbon App ?

(The only difference what I could detect is that the ApplicationMenu appears in the upper side of Window when using a RibbonWindow.)

Comment: Can you explain what you meant by "the upper side" of the window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.ribbon.ribbonwindow(v=vs.110).aspx) it derives from Window, and it adds the possibility to add a Ribbon menu, as you can find [on this sample](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wpf/2010/08/04/bind-my-ribbon-ui-to-my-data-model/).

> (The only difference what I could detect is that the ApplicationMenu
>   appears in the upper side of Window when using a RibbonWindow.)

That is the only difference, yes.

This window type allows you to use a Ribbon with the **Window chrome**, which makes your app looks more like an Office app ([example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131515/WPF-Custom-Chrome-Library)), rather than an old window (you can see on the sample above that you can manipulate your menus and add them to your quick access bar on the window top left).